# subtracting two columns with just date headers adds the time into the resulting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have columns where the headers are dates in the format of yyyy-mm-dd

```
date             2012-01-06  2012-01-13    ...  2021-04-09  2021-04-16                                                    
narnia                    0           0    ...           3           2
```

if i subtract using iloc to identify the columns, the resulting columns headers have the time inserted after the date.

`df['WoW Change'] = df.iloc[:,-1]-df.iloc[:,-2]`

```
date             2012-01-06 00:00:00    2021-04-09 00:00:00   2021-04-16 00:00:00   WoW Change                                                    
narnia                             0                      3                     2           -1
```

how can i avoid this?

Comment: Originally, your columns are a `DatetimeIndex` so all of that information is there, it's just not displayed (and pandas has lots of fancy ways to index based on partial strings). Once you assign a new label, which isn't a date, it upcasts the columns to a plain old `Index` of type `object` and so the `datetime64[ns]` labels get displayed with their full values: `Timestamp('2012-01-06 00:00:00')`. Since it seems like you don't need the functionality of a `DatetimeIndex` (given you destroy it), you can just `df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` before the subtraction

Comment: @ALoliz suppose i have a column which is not in fact a datetime column, what's my best move there to account for that/those?

Comment: You could us a simple list comprehension (or a try/except) like: `[x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x for x in df.columns]`